# How to remove Amazon Assistant that was installed by Java installer?

Tags: windows-7, java, malware

I recently did a clean install of Java about a week or two ago. It asked whether I wanted the Amazon button app installed. I opted NO. It still installed anyway. I removed it from Control Panel -> Programs list and restarted, but `Amazon1ButtonService64.Exe` is still running as a system process and has 2 .DLLs located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon\Amazon1ButtonApp`.

I've tried several virus/malware scanners etc. None of them pick this up.

The issue I have is:

- At no stage did I provide consent to have this installed.
- Program is still running as system process, despite being removed and no longer showing up on browser or programs list.

As far as I'm concerned, this is malware.

Failing safe mode removal, what other options do I have other than an OS reinstall?

EDIT: 
Java installer from here: http://java.com/en/download/windows_xpi.jsp

Images from the above installer:

[image]

Comment: Where did you install Java from?

Comment: From https://java.com/en/download/

Comment: I always download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. Never had any crap installed.

Comment: [Remove Amazon Toolbar (Virus Removal Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/amazon-toolbar-removal/)

Comment: yeah I've removed amazon from toolbar. Issue is/was it was still running as a process behind my back, despite being removed, despite asking not to install it, all without my consent..I've downloaded Java from your link. Is that just drag n drop?

Comment: No, it's a proper install.

Comment: Sue the Bastards!

Comment: never mind, I downloaded the zipped version. Will try the exe version instead.

Comment: You can determine what process has it in memory then, end the process, then delete the files.  Bet this didn't come from Java

Comment: @Ramhound if not from Java, it's a pretty dam good knock off that perhaps is being intercepted?

Comment: Totally as an aside: hitting Alt-PrtScr will only get you the current window/dialog, without the need to crop images.

Comment: Did you restart? (Ah, I guess "Safe mode removal" means you did boot into safe mode and then restarted into regular mode?)

Comment: restart? When I removed it all, yes. When I installed it, well like I already said, I opted NOT to install amazon stuff but it still did anyway, so restart shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you don't want adware and other unwanted stuff with your installs, see if [ninite.com](https://ninite.com/) has what you want. (It has Java.) You can pick several things and have it all installed in one batch to save all the rebooting that some things (e.g. drivers) need during the install.

Answer (score -1):

The official Java installer does not come bundled with any 3rd party software at all.

If you are getting the Amazon software as part of the payload, the only explanation is that either the installer you received wasn't genuine (possibly a browser hijack), or your machine is already infected with malware from another source.

You can check the validity of the Java installer .EXE file by right-clicking it and getting Properties for it.  On the digital signatures tab, it should say Oracle America, Inc.  If it says anything different, or does not have a signatures tab, then the file is not signed and is not a genuine Oracle file.

Comment: Sorry but I respectfully disagree about the installer. I've done all this, I even uploaded the file to https://www.virustotal.com/ & all checks out ok & digital signature is from "Oracle America, Inc". As for my PC already being infected; ok maybe, & I'll dig deeper. I'll update my OP regarding java installer shortly.

Comment: Apparently it does install the Amazon Assistant; see the newly added screenshots.

Comment: Yes it did even though I deselected them.

Comment: The **developer** installers formerly at `sun.com` now `oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase` never offer 3rd-party crud, but the **end-user** ones on `java.com` do -- although (1) when I use them (rarely) I've never had them ignore a deselect and (2) since about a year there is an option (on Java ControlPanel / Advanced at the bottom) that *should* suppress them.

Answer (score -2):

Actually java does come bundled with third party software as you can see here: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/amazon.xml, but it should not be installed without your permission so i do not know why it uninstalled even though you unchecked the box

Comment: This should be a comment, as it is not an answer to the question posted.

Comment: @Haydn Give the guy a break. As you can see, he's a noob and doesn't have enough rep to leave a comment. A mod can come by and convert his answer to a comment if need be.